# python - keep "other" element in a list under if conditions

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings like the following:

```
L = ['aa','bb','cc']
```

I would like to apply an `if` condition on its elements to check if multiple strings are in it, and then keep only one element as result. The pseudo-code I'm trying to implement is:

```
if 'aa' in L AND 'cc' in L:
    return the third element (i.e. 'bb')
else:
    return 'aa'
```

So far I've been working with a list comprehension like:

```
 return = ['aa' if elem != 'aa' and elem != 'cc' else elem for elem in L][0]
```

But it doesn't work as expected.

EDIT:

Fixed return as element and not a list.

Comment: if `L = ['aa','bb','cc','dd']`, what the result is. your pseudo-code return one element, but your list comprehension code return a list. it is confused

Comment: Yes sorry, L can contain at the maximum three elements. The return of a list was actually part of the problem I was trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with a single list comprehension. How about:

```
L = ['aa','bb','cc']
if "aa" in L and "cc" in L:
    result = [item for item in L if item != "aa" and item != "cc"][0]
else:
    result = "aa"
return result
```

Or `return [item for item in L if item != "aa" and item != "cc"][0] if "aa" in L and "cc" in L else "aa"` if you insist on doing it in one line.

Comment: Thanks. Since I have to parse ton of lists in a for loop I thought in a way to avoid multiple if statements, but actually it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the difference between your lists using sets:

```
l = ['aa','bb','cc']
k = ['aa','cc']

if len(list(set(l) - set(k))) == 1:
    return list(set(l) - set(k))
else:
    return l[0]
```

If they return exactly one element return that, otherwise the first element of l.